# XML query error

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have a below XML query:

If I use a variable as below I am getting error like

> 'The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string
>   literal'

Please suggest

```
DECLARE @ElementName varchar(32)
DECLARE @ElementXpath varchar(32)
SET @ElementName = 'Name'
SET @ElementXpath = '//ns1:UserName'
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.google/services/CommonElementsV2_3' AS ns1)                         
                    SELECT @XMLValue =
                       t.c.value('ns1:'''+@ElementName+'''[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') 
                    FROM @xml.nodes(''+@ElementXpath+''') AS t(c);
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes, it would be very kind of you to upvote and/or mark as accepted, thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use local-name() and sql:variable() to find your node:

```
declare @xml XML='<root><row1>1</row1><row2>2</row2></root>';
declare @nodeName varchar(max)='row2';
select @xml.value('(/root/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@nodeName")])[1]','int')
```